# What is the correct way to add a surface positional argument to the pygame draw method?

Tags: python, class, pygame

I am trying to use the draw method to update the screen in pygame.

However I get the following error when I run my program:

```
➜  Stars python3 stars.py
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.6)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/python/Stars/stars.py", line 93, in <module>
    st.run_game()
  File "/Users/Desktop/python/Stars/stars.py", line 31, in run_game
    self._update_screen()
  File "/Users/Desktop/python/Stars/stars.py", line 84, in _update_screen
    star_draw.draw(self.screen)
TypeError: draw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'surface'
```

My program consists of three python files: stars.py, star.py, and settings.py.

stars.py contains the Stars class which manages the 'game'.

star.py contains the Star class which manages a single star.

settings.py contains the Settings class which manages the screen settings.

stars.py:

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from star import Star
# Make a grid of stars appear on the screen
# /images/star.bmp
# A class to manage a star
class Stars:
    """Overall class to manage the game."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game and create game resources."""
        # Initialize pygame.
        pygame.init()
        # Make an instance of the Settings class and assign it.
        self.settings = Settings()
        # Make a screen with dimensions defined in the settings module.
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        # Set a caption on the pygame.
        pygame.display.set_caption("Stars")
        # Create a group for the stars.
        self.stars = pygame.sprite.Group()
        # Add an attribute that is a method to create stars.
        self._create_stars()
        self.star = Star(self)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """Respond to keypresses."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()

    def _create_stars(self):
        """Create a sky full of stars."""
        # Create a star and find the number of stars in a row.
        # Spacing between each star is equal to two star widths.
        star = Star(self)
        star_width, star_height = star.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (star_width)
        number_stars_x = available_space_x // (2 * star_width)

        # Determine the number of rows of stars that fit on the screen.
        # Fill most of the screen with stars.
        available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height - (2 * star_height))
        number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * star_height)

        # Fill the sky with stars.
        # For every row in the total amount of rows.
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            # For every star in the total amount of stars.
            for star_number in range(number_stars_x):
                # Call _create_star with the loops as arguments.
                self._create_star(star_number, row_number)

    def _create_star(self, star_number, row_number):
        """Create a star and place it in the row."""
        star = Star(self)
        star_width, star_height = star.rect.size
        star.x = star_width + (2 * star_width) * star_number
        star.rect.x = star.x
        star.rect.y = star.rect.height + (2 * star.rect.height) * row_number
        # Add the star to the group stars.
        self.stars.add(star)

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        # Draw the star on the screen
        self.star.draw(self.screen)
        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    st = Stars()
    st.run_game()
```

star.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Star(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """A class to manage a single star."""

    def __init__(self, star_game):
        """Initialize the star and set it's starting position."""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = star_game.screen

        # Load the star image and set its rect attribute.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/star.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each new star near the top left of the screen.
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        # Store the star's exact vertical position.
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        self.draw = pygame.sprite.Group.draw
```

settings.py:

```
class Settings:
    """A class to store all settings for the star game."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings."""
        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (50, 50, 50)
```

Comment: Sorry, I initially accepted it before I had a chance to try the change. The change you suggested gave me another error. I will re-accept the answer, because I believe it solves one problem, but here is the error I get after implementing the changes, can you help me understand it?

  File "/Users/Desktop/python/Stars/stars.py", line 83, in _update_screen
    self.star.draw(self.screen)
AttributeError: 'Star' object has no attribute 'draw'

Comment: It is `self.stars.draw(self.screen)`! focus on the `s` (plural). The _Group_ instance is `self.stars`. I mentioned that in my answer. Please read the answer carefully.

Comment: My fault, I re-accepted the question, if you removed an upvote from my question, do you mind restoring it?

Comment: Thank you for catching my typo, it's working!! :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) is a method. It must be called with an instance of [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.).

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The former delegates the to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group [...]

The later uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

Remove the line `self.draw = pygame.sprite.Group.draw` it is misleading. The `Star` object doesn't need a `draw` method, because it's drawn by the *Group*.

Just call:

```py
self.stars.draw(self.screen)
```

Method `_update_screen`:

```py
class Stars:
    # [...]

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        
        # Draw the star on the screen
        self.stars.draw(self.screen)        # <--
        
        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()
```